# C# Pattern Matching Failure

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

Here is the code I am using to find transit numbers of the form RB\d{4}, SW\d{4} and S\d{4}:

```
Regex transitRegex = new Regex("^(RB|SW?)(<?transit>\\d{4}).*");
Match m1 = transitRegex.Match(transitNumber);
if (m1.Success)
{
    Regex transitRegexNoZeroes = new Regex("0+(<?transitNoZeroes>\\d+)");
    Match m2 = transitRegexNoZeroes.Match(m1.Groups["transit"].Value);
    if (m2.Success)
    {
        transitNumber = m2.Groups["transitNoZeroes"].Value.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(transitNumber, "Transit Number", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
    else
    {
        transitNumber = m1.Groups["transit"].Value.ToString();
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Could not find transit number in " + transitNumber, "Parsing Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

However I am failing to match any lines.  Here is an example of a line that fails:

```
RB80720C1XX -  Intermittent COMM lOSS ****CHRONIC****
```

For the life of me I can't figure out what's wrong with the regex.  Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

EDIT:  Inner match edited to allow numbers with leading zeroes to still contain zeroes.

Comment: What is the goal of non-zeroes?  It currently finds a number that possibly starts with a zero, and contains no zeros.  In the case above, it *should* return 72 (at least at first glance).

Comment: Have you made sure that your lines have no leading spaces?

Comment: To answer both questions.  I removed the "^" in case of leading spaces but the results were the same.  As for the non-zeroes, I know that each transit number is represented by four digits following those particular letter codes.  These numbers might contain leading zeroes that need to be stripped in order to be compared to transit numbers in a different format.  You are right that the inner match is incorrect inasmuch as the stripped number could still legally contain zeroes -- but I am not even getting to the inner code.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clear that it's the outer match that is failing on the example input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first pattern is a little off. Try this instead:

```
@"^(RB|SW?)(?<transit>\d{4})"
```

Note, the position of the question mark. You can test the pattern [here](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx).

Comment: [Hits forehead with hand]  Thanks so much!  All I was doing was looking at the regex.  I totally missed that syntax error.